# python-daemon does not do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-daemon

I want to use the pip package python-daemon to daemonize one of my tasks, but I can't get it to run even with the most simple example I can think of.

The following code snipplet displays "Hallo" und logs the "Before with statement", but doesn't do anything else.

The pid-File for the daemon will be created and deleted and the job lasts longer if you put in some time.sleep() inside, but it doesn't log anything.
The "After with.." also never shows up in the log.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# pip3 install python-daemon
import daemon
import lockfile
import logging


LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="/tmp/test.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()

context = daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory='/tmp/',
                               pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/tmp   /test.pid'),
                               )

logger.info("Before with statement")
print("Hallo")

with context:
    logger.info("Info")

logger.info("After with statement")
```

Comment: why do you think the logger/config will survive daemonization..? (it's not the same process anymore)

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem apparently

Comment: The real question is why doesn't it survive daemonization?  It doesn't matter that it's not the same process as there is quite a lot preserved when forking.  The issue is that daemonizing often means [closing open file handles](https://pagure.io/python-daemon/blob/master/f/daemon/daemon.py#_88).  As a result, the daemon process loses access to the log file and you see no more entries.  [Linux Application Development](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321563220/) has a lot of useful information about daemonizing and many other topics.

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend this as a solution, but you can see your example continue to log if you add `files_preserve=[3,4,5]` to your `DaemonContext()` call.

Comment: Ok, that works as well. Where does this [3, 4, 5] come from?

Comment: FYI: you didn't include my username in the message, so I never got notified of your response.  The `[3, 4, 5]` is a list of file handles to leave open.  Unix systems generally start from 0 and go up from there.  0 being stdin, 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr.  3, 4, and 5 are the next available handles.  It's a complete guess (which is why I don't recommend it), but it's enough to make the example work.  Again, you don't want to do this, just showing that it's not necessarily a separate process problem and handles are being closed).